# Java class is present in classpath but startup fails with Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, classnotfoundexception, classloading

I have a jar file `foobar.jar` containing the following two classes:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

The other class looks like this:

```
import javax.batch.api.chunk.ItemProcessor;

public class Bar implements ItemProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Bar");
    }

    @Override
    public Object processItem(Object item) throws Exception {
        return item;
    }
}
```

If I execute the program using the following command, the program behaves as expected and prints `Foo`:

```
$ java -cp foobar.jar Foo
Foo
$
```

But if I try to start the program using the main method in the class `Bar`, the JVM prints a startup error and exits:

```
$ java -cp foobar.jar Bar
Error: Could not find or load main class Bar
$
```

This is the same error as if I would try to start the program using a class which is not in the jar, e.g.

```
$ java -cp foobar.jar BarNotThere
Error: Could not find or load main class BarNotThere
$
```

Why do I get this error? The fact that the `Foo.main` method can be started and I'm able to decompile the class `Bar` from the jar proves, that the class should be available on the classpath. I realize that this could have something to do with the interface `ItemProcessor` not being on the classpath. But shouldn't I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` in that case?

Comment: Please note that this problem is partially covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean. I ran into this problem and tried to solve it using said question. But at first I wasn't able to solve it, because the problem with the superclass not being on the classpath is kind of an edge case. This is why I added this particular case as a new Q/A.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is indeed that the interface `ItemProcessor` is not on the classpath. Notice that the error states "**find** or **load** main class". In the case of `BarNotThere` the JVM is really not able to **find** the main class. But in the `Bar` case, it is not able to **load** the main class.

In order to completely load a class, the JVM also need instances of each superclass objects. During this process for `Bar`, the JVM tries to load the class object for `ItemProcessor`. But since this interface is not on the classpath, loading of the main class `Bar` fails and the startup terminates with the `Error: Could not find or load main class Bar`.

If you struggle with finding the problematic class in question (because the is no message saying so), you can use the `jdeps` tool to inspect the classpath. Just use the same classpath, but run `jdeps` instead of `java`:

```
$ jdeps -cp foobar.jar Bar
foobar.jar -> java.base
foobar.jar -> not found
   <unnamed> (foobar.jar)
      -> java.io
      -> java.lang
      -> javax.batch.api.chunk                              not found
```

*(This was created using openjdk-9, actual output may vary heavily depending on the Java version)*

This should give you enough hints as where to look for the missing class.

---

*Further explanation*

Notice the difference between loading and initializing a class. If classloading fails during initialization (which means the class was successfully **found** and **loaded**), you will get your expected `ClassNotFoundException`. See the following example:

```
import javax.batch.api.chunk.ItemProcessor;

public class FooBar {

    private static ItemProcessor i = new ItemProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Object processItem(Object item) throws Exception {
            return item;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

In this case, the class `FooBar` can be loaded during startup. But it can not be initialized, since the static field `i` needs the `ItemProcessor` class, which is not on the classpath. Initialization is a precondition if a static method on a class is executed, which is the case, when the JVM tries to invoke the `main` method.

```
$ java -cp foobar.jar FooBar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/batch/api/chunk/ItemProcessor
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.batch.api.chunk.ItemProcessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
$
```

Comment: But how can I know which class is not on the classpath when `Error: Could not find or load main class Bar` occur?

Comment: @zczhuohuo You could use the `jdeps` tool to analyze the classpath. I'll add this to the answer.